# Does Haskell's ghci support running a script and then quit, like python or perl?

Tags: haskell, scripting, ghci

Python or Perl supports:

```
python xxx.py
perl xxx.pl
powershell xxx.ps1
```

Execute the script and quit with an exit code. When I tried GHCi (as `ghci xxx.hs`) it seems to load the `xxx.hs` file and enter interactive mode, without quiting.

1. Does the GHC interpreter support such operations?
2. Does this "interpreting" require to have a `main` function like the GHC compiler does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `runghc` to get the same behavior. You will indeed need a `main :: IO ()` function still.

Comment: You can "run" an arbitrary expression defined at the top level (i.e. evaluate and print) with `ghc -e "expr" file.hs`. The expression can be a pure value, or an IO value. If the type inside the IO value is anything but `()` (i.e. `IO Int`, `IO Bool`, etc) then the IO action is run, and its result is printed.